# Why does numeric_limits<atomic<X>> not fail to compile?

Tags: c++, atomic, decltype

I just created a bug by testing a value against the following expression:

```cpp
std::numeric_limits<decltype(allocationCount)>::max()
```

In this context, `allocationCount` is a `std::atomic<std::size_t>`.

Apparently, the above mentioned expression [compiles and evaluates to 0 on both Clang 10 and GCC 10](https://godbolt.org/z/9LZxXm):

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

static std::atomic<std::size_t> allocationCount = 0;

uint64_t buggyGetMax() {
    return std::numeric_limits<decltype(allocationCount)>::max();
}

uint64_t correctGetMax() {
    return std::numeric_limits<decltype(allocationCount)::value_type>::max();
}
```

What I meant to use was

```cpp
std::numeric_limits<decltype(allocationCount)::value_type>::max()
```

that produces the value I wanted, that is `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`.

---

The question I have is why `std::numeric_limits<decltype(allocationCount)>` even compiled? Shouldn't it fail as `std::numeric_limits<std::string>` does?

If this is by design, why is the `max()` 0?

Comment: Do you have an example where `std::numeric_limits<std::string>` fails?  It works fine [here](https://godbolt.org/z/GBrQtB)

Comment: @NathanOliver https://godbolt.org/z/n59uSM ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the default behavior.  From [[numeric.limits]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/numeric.limits)

> 2. For all members declared static constexpr in the `numeric_­limits` template, specializations shall define these values in such a way that they are usable as constant expressions.
> 3. The default `numeric_­limits<T>` template shall have all members, but with `0` or `false` values.
> 4. Specializations shall be provided for each arithmetic type, both floating-point and integer, including bool. The member `is_­specialized` shall be `true` for all such specializations of `numeric_­limits`.
> 5. The value of each member of a specialization of `numeric_­limits` on a cv-qualified type cv `T` shall be equal to the value of the corresponding member of the specialization on the unqualified type `T`.
> 6. Non-arithmetic standard types, such as `complex<T>`, shall not have specializations.

So, since `std::atomic<T>` is a non-arithmetic type, it shall not have a specialization per paragraph 6 and that means paragraph 3 comes into play and all values you get will be `0` or `false`.

Comment: I see. I think I just assumed numeric_limits<T> would not default to anything, but only compile if specialized. Is there an explanation about why there is an all-zero default?

Comment: @BernardoSulzbach I'm not sure why this decision was made.  It might have made writing generic code before C++11 easier since C++98/03 didn't come with <type_traits>

Answer (score 4):

`std::numeric_limits<T>` has a default implementation when it does not have a specialization for `T`.

So, when `T=std::string` and `T=std::atomic<size_t>`, `std::numeric_limits` will still compile fine, it will just report default values.

However, inside of your `buggyGetMax()` function, which returns a `uint64_t`, returning `std::numeric_limits<std::string>::max()` will not compile because `max()` returns an empty `std::string` which does not implicitly convert to `uint64_t`.  But `std::atomic<size_t>` does implicitly convert to `uint64_t`, which is why returning `std::numeric_limits<std::atomic<std::size_t>>::max()` compiles.  It just won't return the value you are expecting.